# How to correctly override method which raises an event

Tags: .net, vb.net, events, inheritance, overriding

I have a class MyCol, which inherits from ObservableCollection(Of T). It overrides InsertItem method in such manner:

```
Public Event PreInsertItem As EventHandler(Of EventArgs)

Protected Overridable Sub OnPreInsertItem(e As EventAtgs)
    RaiseEvent PreInsertItem(Me, e)
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub InsertItem(index As Integer, item As T)
    OnPreInsertItem(EventArgs.Empty)

    MyBase.InsertItem(index, item)
End Sub
```

As you can see I have added an event which is raised every time an item is added to MyCol collection.

Next I create another class MyColSubClass, which inherits from MyCol, and also overrides InsertItem method:

```
Public Overrides Sub InsertItem(index as Integer, item as T)
    OnPreInsertItem(EventArgs.Empty)

    ' some additional code goes here

    MyBase.InsertItem(index, item)
End Sub
```

**THE QUESTION:**

Now, when I use an instance of MyColSubClass and add an item, *PreInsertItem* event is raised twice: first in MyColSubClass and than in MyCol.

What design pattern should I use to make PreInsertItem event raise only once: in MyColSubClass?

N.B.

Classes and events, shown in examples are simplified from real life application, but assume they show exact structure of application. Raising event in last inherited class is a must.

Comment: Why call `OnPreInsertItem(EventArgs.Empty)` at all from the sub-class?  It's already going to get called when you do `MyBase.InsertItem(index, item)`.

Comment: Here I showed a simplified example. In real application a lot of data is passed in event data. So event must be called in each inherited class (i.e. MyColSubClass).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know for sure that the base class will raise the event, it's useless to do so in the derived class.

Just change your override to :

```
Public Overrides Sub InsertItem(index as Integer, item as T)
    ' some additional code goes here

    MyBase.InsertItem(index, item)
End Sub
```

And that should be fine.

But if you change your derived method, and stop calling MyBase.InsertItem(...), you should raise the event in your override to ensure it gets raised :

```
Public Overrides Sub InsertItem(index as Integer, item as T)
    ' some additional code goes here

    OnPreInsertItem(EventArgs.Empty)

    ' insert your item and do whatever...
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

If you need to change the way the event is raised, but want to make sure that it only gets raised once, simply override the OnPreInsertItem method in your derived class :

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnPreInsertItem(e as EventArgs)
    ' Do wahetever you need here, change e, add info, whatever...
    ' ...
    ' Then raise the event (or call MyBase.OnPreInsertItem, as you like)
    RaiseEvent PreInsertItem(Me, e)
End Sub

Public Overrides Sub InsertItem(index as Integer, item as T)
    ' some additional code goes here

    ' This will work only if MyBase.InsertItem calls OnPreInsertItem. 
    ' Otherwise, you have to handle the insertion and raise the event
    ' yourself without calling the base method.
    MyBase.InsertItem(index, item)
End Sub
```

Since OnPreInsertItem is overridable, the version from your derived class will get called when you insert an item in your derived class.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: There is a simplified example in my question. In real application I have to raise event before any additional code, as event passes a lot of data (again, in real app).

Comment: Great solution in your last edit! Thanks, that really helped, don't know how I've missed it myself :)

Comment: If i'm not completely wrong if you remove MyBase.InsertItem in you base class (MyCol), the item doesn't get added to the ObservableCollection which would render this example useless.

Comment: You're right, **if** he removes MyBase.InsertItem from MyCol. Which I'm pretty confident he won't do, and if he does, he'll revert his change pretty quickly :)

Comment: @T.Fabre Bad reading, my bad :) Still confused tho what OP tried to achieve then when calling OnPreInsertItem() twice. Quite obvious to remove one call.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should raise `OnPreInsertItem` in your sub-class MyColSubClass.
Your method should be like this:

```
Public Overrides Sub InsertItem(index as Integer, item as T)
    ' some additional code goes here

    MyBase.InsertItem(index, item)
End Sub
```

You're extending some functionality of your base class. 
If you are replacing that particular functionality then your method should be like this:

```
Public Overrides Sub InsertItem(index as Integer, item as T)
    OnPreInsertItem(EventArgs.Empty)

    ' some additional code goes here

End Sub
```

You can find more infos [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_overriding) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implementation_inheritance#Overriding).

Answer (score 0):

If i got it right you want to add information to your EventArg class on differenct levels of inheritance. Under that circumstances providing a EventArg member at the same level as the event get raised is in my opinion the best solution, while all overrides of InsertItem() just modify this EventArg member the event along with this eventargs is getting raised only on the highest possible level.